# Error handling API calls with axios Interceptors. Am I doing this right?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, axios

Hello I'am completly new with React/Redux so there is a possibility that I violated some principles with the below code , so bare with me.

I'm building a React App which will consume my Express API. Everything is working perfectly but when I was building the Action Creators I couldnt think of a good way to handle any errors coming from the API without wrapping every single axios request with `try/catch` blocks.

Both in PHP world where I come from and Express you can create a global Error handler.

For any async requests in my Express APP I wrap them with the below function so I can catch them the same way as the synchronous.

```
module.exports = (fn) => {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    fn(req, res, next).catch((err) => next(err));
  };
};
```

From what I've learned through googling is that, there is an ErrorBoundary HOC for handling errors inside Components and for axios calls I should use axios interceptors. So I created this:

AxiosFactory Class

```
import axios from "axios";
import { setError } from "../actions/utilActions";
import store from "../store";

class AxiosFactory {
  constructor(baseURL) {
    this.instance = axios.create({
      baseURL,
    });
    this.instance.interceptors.response.use(
      function (response) {
        // Any status code that lie within the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
        // Do something with response data
        return response;
      },
      function (error) {
        // Any status codes that falls outside the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
        // Do something with response error
        // Getting the errors from Express API
        const {
          response: {
            data: { errors },
          },
        } = error;
        store.dispatch(setError(errors));
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );
  }

  getInstance() {
    return this.instance;
  }
}

export default AxiosFactory;
```

User API Caller

```
import AxiosFactory from './AxiosFactory';
const axios = new AxiosFactory('/api/v1/users/').getInstance();
export default axios;
```

User ActionCreator

```
import { SUCCESS_LOGIN } from "./types/userTypes";
import userApi from "../apis/user";

// Tries to login the user
export const signInUser = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    // Test
    const {data:{data:{user} = await userApi.post("login", {
      email: "test@test.com",
      password: "test12345!",
    });
    dispatch({
      type: SUCCESS_LOGIN,
      payload: user,
    });
}
```

Error ActionCreator

```
import { HAS_ERROR } from "./types/utilTypes";

export const setError = (errors) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: HAS_ERROR,
      payload: errors,
    });
  };
};
```

The interceptor dispatches succesfuly the `setError` and the error state is getting updated like a charm, which means I dont need to manual dispatch on each call. Although I still need to catch the Promise rejection from Interceptor.

My 2 questions are:

1. Is there a way to lets say "stop the dispatch from executing" inside my User ActionCreator without try/catching the Promise ?
2. Does this whole thing I setup makes sense ? Or there is a better way to do it?

Comment: 2. To use interceptors is good enough. Other way is to make a wrapper class on top of axios like you did, but add get post .etc methods with error handling.
1. Not really get what you want. But if I get it you have distuctured only user data, but you need all response where you can find status, and if there is and error you do not dispatch SUCCESS_LOGIN

Comment: Was thinking of something like a wrapper function that will take the axios request as argument and only dispatch the action if there is no promise rejected. So I wont have to put try/catch blocks on each actionCreator.